# How to know caller function when tracing assertion failure

Tags: c++, function

My question is related to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8556693/984260) and some others [alike](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1586498/984260). I wanted to know the name of caller function, since at the time of assertion failure, I don't know which function passed a garbage value to callee. One method is to put check in all the functions which could call this function, but that is very cumbersome.

Can you suggest a better solution, even though platform-dependent? I am using g++ 4.6. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just run the program in a debugger to see the stack trace?

Comment: there are many use cases where you can't do this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See `backtrace()`.

e.g.

```
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void bar() {
  void* callstack[128];
  int i, frames = backtrace(callstack, 128);
  char** strs = backtrace_symbols(callstack, frames);
  for (i = 0; i < frames; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", strs[i]);
  }
  free(strs);
}

int foo() {
  bar();
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0   a.out                               0x0000000100000e24 bar + 28
1   a.out                               0x0000000100000e81 foo + 14
2   a.out                               0x0000000100000e96 main + 14
3   a.out                               0x0000000100000e00 start + 52
4   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

See:

[How to generate a stacktrace when my gcc C++ app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes)

Answer (score 5):

You have [backtrace](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_665.html) functions in glibc. It can allow you to have full trace, with the caller function or method.

If you only want the caller, there's also [specific functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) in **gcc** just for this :

```
__builtin_frame_address(int level);
```

With `level == 1` you have the caller function. See [this post](http://stupefydeveloper.blogspot.com/2009/09/cc-call-stack-v2.html) for more detail about how to use it.

Here is the sample program which is in the documentation :

```
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Obtain a backtrace and print it to stdout. */
void
print_trace (void)
{
  void *array[10];
  size_t size;
  char **strings;
  size_t i;

  size = backtrace (array, 10);
  strings = backtrace_symbols (array, size);

  printf ("Obtained %zd stack frames.\n", size);

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
     printf ("%s\n", strings[i]);

  free (strings);
}

/* A dummy function to make the backtrace more interesting. */
void
dummy_function (void)
{
  print_trace ();
}

int
main (void)
{
  dummy_function ();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I find it convenient to also emit the results of `backtrace` itself (the raw pointers). You can then use the `addr2line` command-line utility to convert it to actual source file names and line numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how to get the name of the function? This only seems to print some addresses. Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: In strings[i], you have functions name and with dlinfo of the other link, it can even show you more information